# Best practices to update across multiples of HTML-only templates?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, ssi, frontend

One option is to use SSI but want to know if there are good alternatives?

At my work, working on mostly front-end stuff for clients, I deal with HTML-only templates and the caveat is that whenever shared data (ie: `header`, `footer`, `components`) changes, we have to manually update all templates.

Would `jQuery.load("footer.html")` be a reasonable alternative? Or is there some third-party tooling/plug-in out there for templaters like us?

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: SSI has the advantage of jQuery of providing SEO for the injected content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Template Toolkit?

It's a perl module.

In a nutshell it allows you do do this:

```
[% PROCESS header.inc 
    Title = "Sherwood's Forests -- Seedling Sales" 
    Desc = "Sherwood's Forests Pre-season orders for little Trees."
%]

body content goes here. Body could be the text for another template.


[% INCLUDE footer.inc %]
```

Templates can be nested to an unreasonable degree.  (your brain will have stack overflow before you bottom out.)  I've never found a reason to have directives more than about 3 deep.